# Cannot get the PIN to connect with twitter

Tags: r, rcurl, twitter-r, roauth

```
    library(RCurl)
    library(ROAuth)
    consumerKey = "###"
     reqURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
    accessURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
    authURL =  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
    consumerSecret = "####"
    accessToken = "####"
    accessTokenSecret = "####"
    twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new( consumerKey = consumerKey,
                               consumerSecret = consumerSecret,
                               requestURL = reqURL,
                               accessURL = accessURL,
                               authURL = authURL)
    twitCred$handshake()
```

This is the code I tried for linking R to twitter. But it's throwing up an error :

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.twitter.com:443
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?